# Stock Status in backend product overview

Tags: magento-1.9, backend, stock, status

I have a simple question :)

In Backend, the products status is displayed (Active/Inactive) in the Catalog-> Manage Product section. it is also possible to mass-action wether products should be active or inactive.

See: http://screencast.com/t/5LHlczWjKr1

I would like the same for Stock Availability (in stock/out of stock)

two reasons:

- To be able to mass-action "back in stock"
- To get a better overview over, which products are out of stock

Hope someone have an answer :)

- Jack

Answer (score 1):

1. From admin back end first select products you want to edit.
2. Then from actions drop-down select **Update Attributes**.
3. Then click on submit. Now go to inventory tab and change the stock
   status

Hope this will help you !